# nextjs protected layout without DRY like React Router outlet

Tags: authentication, next.js, authorization, next-auth

I am new to next.js has more experience with React, I want to build a dashboard with next.js now I want only authenticated users to be able to see the layout that has the sidebar and the pages without including it per page I looking for a solution similar to when you create a high order component in react that checks if you authenticated and then return an outlet component